# Vox Populi badge - why so few have it?

Tags: discussion, voting, badges

We have 700+ users. Sure many of them are once-off or casual, but only 9 of them have the [Vox Populi badge](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help/badges/71/vox-populi).

The benefit of getting this badge is you're providing encouragement to other users.  If you don't already have this badge, I encourage you to look for good answers and questions, especially recent ones, and give the encouragement and support in the form of votes.

Comment: Note that I vote a lot (only @Gagravarr voted more than me among those that got the badge) and yet I never had the occasion to reach 40 on any given day. So low overall activity and regular participation (I never opened the site to find 100+ new questions I would want to read) can also explain some of it.

Answer (score 10):

I don't think voting is at all unhealthy here, and I do positively encourage folks to remember to up-vote great content.

There's a niche aspect that might cause folks to hold back a bit on *answers*, because exceedingly narrow sub sets of people really are the only ones that know if the answer is helpful or not. In order to vet certain answers you'd either have to Google the heck out of it, or actually *go* there and see for yourself. I thin a bit of that might be at play, but I'm not overly worried about it since we've got users steadily climbing the ranks and unlocking privileges.

I *tend* to give what appear to be well written and thorough answers an vote, even if I'm not *entirely* sure the post is 100% correct (but seems to be from the searching I did) - but I don't know how many have that much time to put into browsing / voting on content.

Comment: Indeed, if a user has provided links, quotes and what appears to be good information, I give them a vote as well.  I've found on travel at least, over time mistakes get found eventually by those with expert specific knowledge as it is. We can't all research every answer.